# How to point a URL to a different address for static content and point it back to the same address

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL www.example.com. This should point to the page www.test.com and show the content in www.test.com but in the URL box it should show www.example.com

My present configuration in vhost.conf for rewrite file is

```
RewriteEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ www.test.com
ProxyPassReverse  / www.exapmle.com
```

Comment: You should use domain aliases :
ServerName www.test.com
ServerAlias test.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to redirect the entire www.example.com to www.test.com, do this:

```
ProxyPass        "/"    "http://www.test.com"
ProxyPassReverse "/"    "http://www.test.com"
```

---

Like @paglofr pointed out, if you control both sites, you could do this:

- change the IP in the DNS of www.example.com to the IP address of www.test.com
- In the VirtualHost for www.test.com, add this:

  ```
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ```
- Remove the VirtualHost www.example.com

Comment: I do not have control over the sites. I have the same configuration for other domain adding a [P] flag at the end of Rewriterule and it works fine. However, for this particular domain, it gives a 502 proxy error.

Comment: Anything in the logs (set your `LogLevel debug` before trying).  When using a `RewriteRule` with flag `[P]`,  you do not need the `ProxyPassReverse`.  Oh and I made a mistake in my answer, please look again.  I put both times `ProxyPass`.  and make sure you load mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http.